# What happened in the function convert(&m)?

Tags: c++, post-increment

Here is the code:

```
int convert(int* a) {
    return (*a)++;
}

int main(){
    int m = 56;
    int n = convert(&m);
    cout << m << endl;
    m = convert(&m);
    cout << m << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the answer `m=57` instead of `m=58` after `m=convert(&m)`?

Comment: Fix this by not doing really strange things inside functions. _Either_ return the new value _or_ adjust the parameter. Don't do both at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second call increments `m` to 58, but it returns the original value (57) due to the use of the post-increment `++` operator. That original value is then assigned back to `m`, overwriting the incremented value. The net effect is that `m` is unchanged.

You can verify this by adding some printouts to see the exact values in play:

```
int convert(int* a) {
    std::cout << "*a was " << *a << std::endl;
    int ret = (*a)++;
    std::cout << "*a is now " << *a << std::endl;
    std::cout << "return value is " << ret << std::endl;
    return ret;
}
```

`m = convert(&m);` prints:

```
*a was 57
*a is now 58
return value is 57
```